# Flutter multiline chart from Json Record and json record will increase or decrease on User Selection

Tags: flutter, dart, charts, linechart, syncfusion

Flutter, I have This Type of Json from api i want to show multiline chart of every user. Users can increase or decrease on district basis selection inside application? I searched alot from Syncfusion library or from many others but i didnot find any way please help.

```
**[{"id":"1", "name":"fayyaz","date":"12-1-2021","count":"5"},
    {"id":"1", "name":"fayyaz","date":"13-1-2021","count":"7"},
    {"id":"1", "name":"fayyaz","date":"14-1-2021","count":"2"},
    {"id":"1", "name":"fayyaz","date":"15-1-2021","count":"15"},
    {"id":"1", "name":"fayyaz","date":"16-1-2021","count":"10"},
    {"id":"2", "name":"ali","date":"14-1-2021","count":"3"},
    {"id":"2", "name":"ali","date":"16-1-2021","count":"6"},
    {"id":"3", "name":"saad","date":"12-1-2021","count":"1"},
    {"id":"3", "name":"saad","date":"13-1-2021","count":"10"},
    {"id":"3", "name":"saad","date":"14-1-2021","count":"4"},
    {"id":"3", "name":"saad","date":"15-1-2021","count":"3"}];**


 SfCartesianChart(
                                          plotAreaBorderWidth: 0,
                                          title: ChartTitle(text: 'Monthly Progress'),
                                          legend: Legend(
                                              isVisible: isCardView ? false : true,
                                              overflowMode: LegendItemOverflowMode.wrap),
                                          primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
                                            // Axis will be rendered based on the index values
                                              interval: 1,
                                              labelRotation: 90,
                                              arrangeByIndex: true
                                          ),
                                          primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
                                              edgeLabelPlacement: EdgeLabelPlacement.shift,
                                              // labelFormat: '{value}k',
                                              // minimum: 0,
                                              // maximum: 12,
                                              axisLine: const AxisLine(width: 0),
                                              majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(color: Colors.transparent)
                                          ),
                                          tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(enable: true),
                                          series: <ChartSeries<MonthlyCount, String>>
                                          [
                                            LineSeries<MonthlyCount, String>(
                                              animationDuration: 2500,
                                              width: 2,
                                              name: '',
                                              markerSettings: const MarkerSettings(isVisible: true),
                                              dataSource: chartDataMonthlyCount!,
                                              xValueMapper: (MonthlyCount sales, _) => sales.xaxis,
                                              yValueMapper: (MonthlyCount sales, _) => sales.collectCount,
                                            ),

                                          ]

                                      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

first use this site [quichtype](https://app.quicktype.io/) to create a model class from your json. then you can use this model to set data for charts.
after you generate your model class from above site, let's call it `User` class. you can use it like this.

```
var json = jsonDecode(PutYourJsonHere);
List<Users> UsersList = json.map((e) => User.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

Comment: Sir i did this part But How To Add Multiline chart Code Can you please help.

Comment: `Syncfusion` has multiline chart. if you couldn't do that. Share you code so i can edit it for you.

Comment: I want to add LineSeries Dynamically not Duplicating it

Answer (score 0):

We created a sample for your requirement that will parse given JSON data and convert it into multiple lists of a data source based on the id value in the JSON and rendered multiple line series. We have attached the code snippet below and KB for your reference.

KB: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/11674/how-to-render-a-flutter-chart-using-the-json-data-sfcartesianchart

code snippet

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<SalesData> chartData = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    loadSalesData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: getJsonFromAssets(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return SfCartesianChart(
                  primaryXAxis: DateTimeAxis(),
                  series: getLineChart(chartData),
                );
              } else {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            }));
  }

  Future<String> getJsonFromAssets() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data.json');
  }

  Future loadSalesData() async {
    final String jsonString = await getJsonFromAssets();
    final dynamic jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    for (Map<String, dynamic> i in jsonResponse) {
      // for(int i = 0; i < chartData.length)
      chartData.add(SalesData.fromJson(i));
    }
  }

  List<ChartSeries<SalesData, DateTime>> getLineChart(List<SalesData> data) {
    List<ChartSeries<SalesData, DateTime>> series = [];
    List<SalesData> _data = [];
    List<SalesData> _data1 = [];
    List<SalesData> _data2 = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
      chartData[i].id == 1
          ? _data.add(chartData[i])
          : chartData[i].id == 2
              ? _data1.add(chartData[i])
              : _data2.add(chartData[i]);
    }
    series.addAll([
      LineSeries(
          dataSource: _data,
          xValueMapper: (SalesData data, _) => data.date,
          yValueMapper: (SalesData data, _) => data.count),
      LineSeries(
          dataSource: _data1,
          xValueMapper: (SalesData data, _) => data.date,
          yValueMapper: (SalesData data, _) => data.count),
      LineSeries(
          dataSource: _data2,
          xValueMapper: (SalesData data, _) => data.date,
          yValueMapper: (SalesData data, _) => data.count)
    ]);
    return series;
  }
}

class SalesData {
  SalesData({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.date,
    this.count,
  });

  int? id;
  String? name;
  DateTime? date;
  int? count;

  factory SalesData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SalesData(
        id: int.parse(json["id"]),
        name: json["name"],
        date: DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse(json["date"]),
        count: int.parse(json["count"]),
      );
}
```

Comment: Brother thanks for code but still its not solve my problem because my Json can have 40 lines or can 5 or can 1. LineSeries are changing Json is changing on just user click. I can't not hardcore LineSeries in Json maybe I have 40 user data or 1 user data I am stuck on this part..

Comment: I have to add LineSeries dynamically not adding it three times.